# What is a package ID in octopus?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy a release on a tentacle created with Jenkins and deployed in Octopus. The release is created properly and everything is ok, but when I try to deploy it to the server I get an error message that the `The resource 'XXX' was not found`. I know that I have to create in the Process tab a new step but I can not figure it out what should be in the Package ID field.

With what should I fill that field or how can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OctopusDeploy application's abilities are deploying a nuget package and could run powershell scripts on tentacles.It has an API called Octo.exe. I think you are triggering a Jenkins Job, that's creating release and deploying with Octo.exe.

Also nuget package feed is very important. You must be sure, that the package is exists in the OctopusDeploy project's nuget feed. You should use Octopus built-in nuget package feed or your existing custom nuget feed server. I suggest to you using Octopus built-in nuget feed. Also nuget package versioning is very important, You must increment the nuget package version number. If you don't, you should fail when you are pushing your package to nuget feed.

Package ID in Octopus is nuget package ID. It's name must match with your csprojname.nuspec file. If it does not match, You should fail. If the problem is going on please give us more information about the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try it and get back to you :)